# PHP Soap: Set attribute to tag in array

Tags: php, xml, soap

i'm creating a array to use in soapclient, and one tag in the middle of xml needs attributes, how can i set this in my array?

Case:

```
<FileDelivery xsi:type="FileDeliveryToFtp" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <FtpAddress>ftohost</FtpAddress>
     <UserName>ftuser</UserName>
     <NotificationEmail>notificationemail</NotificationEmail>
     <Password>ftppasswd</Password>
</FileDelivery>
```

--Edit

If this don't have the attributes, I could create an array like this:

```
"FileDelivery"=>array(
                            "FtpAddress"=>"",
                            "UserName"=>"",
                            "NotificationEmail"=>"",
                            "Password"=>""
                            )
```

But I need set the attributes, so how I can do that?

Ps: This needs to be array, not an object.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to add an attribute inside an element of the XML above? What array are you talking about? What XML tooling do you have experience with? SimpleXML? DOMDocument?

Comment: @Michael I edit now, see if you can help me!